# How to connect External Crystal to AVR32DA28

Tags: avr32

I am trying to find any document on connecting External Crystal in AVR32DA28 and the **XTAL32K2** and **XTAL32K1** pins only supports 32 khz external crystal and any other value of crystal can be connected on **EXTCLK** pin but i can not figure out the way to connect the crystal on single pin. I know it might be a simple connection but i am new in this Embedded system so it will be really appreciable if someone can help me.
**The value i want to connect is 16MHZ Crystal.**

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the data sheet, you can't connect a crystal to that device.

> **11.3.3.2.2 External Clock (EXTCLK)**
> The EXTCLK is taken directly from the pin. This GPIO pin is automatically configured for the EXTCLK if any
> peripheral requests this clock.
> The maximum input frequency for the EXTCLK is 24 MHz.
> This clock source has a start-up time of two cycles when first requested.

You need a dedicated crystal oscillator, which will provide an output that you can connect to EXTCLK.

Comment: Value Name Description
0x0 OSCHF Internal high-frequency oscillator --
0x1 OSC32K 32.768 kHz internal oscillator -- 
0x2 XOSC32K 32.768 kHz external crystal oscillator -- 
0x3 EXTCLK External clock  --> At first i have to select this bit to unable the external clock setting is this correct.

Comment: sorry to say but what do you mean by dedicated crystal oscillator.

Comment: Yes, you have to configure the MCLKCTRLA register to 0x03 EXTCLK. "crystals" require additional circuitry to make them oscillate. Many controllers provide such a circuit internally, requiring two external capacitors and the crystal only. This controller does not have such a oscillator circuit and thus requires a "real" external clock signal (square wave). You can buy "Crystal oscillators" that contain the whole oscillator circuit including the crystal, which provide a "clock out" pin that can be fed into EXTCLK for example.

Comment: I have another question can you please help me to make a pwm with two signals one with inverted and another with non inverted, i tried a lot  to achieve this but somehow it is getting more and more complex for me compare to atmega series.

Comment: @RjChoudhary Please vote and accept this answer if it is resolved and ask a new question about the PWM because its not related to this one.

Comment: could you give me some references for clock generator that will help me to find more specific ones.

Comment: Something like LFSPXO018038. That is a 16MHz 3.3V oscillator. You can also find oscillators DIP-8 packages. But the example should get you started. Standalone CRYSTALS normally have two pins, where oscillators have at least 3 or 4 pins: Vcc, GND, OUT and sometimes ENABLE.